# Accessing asp temporary directory from code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

Is there any method to retrieve the value of tempdirectory while Web App is running ? By method I mean any API (e.g. `Path.GetTempPath())`

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" tempDirectory="some path" targetFramework="4.6" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
```

I want to avoid reading config file directly.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just read configSection.TempDirectory in the System.Web.Configuration namespace?

This is documented in MSDN at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.compilationsection.tempdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx